# Generating time in 5 seconds interval

Tags: c#, random

I need to generate time with a 5 second interval where the user selects a date and a specific time interval, e.g. from 11:00:00 to 12:00:00. The program should then generate a record like this:

1. date       time      random number
2. 23/01/2016 11:02:02   030
3. 23/01/2016 11:02:07   035
4. 23/01/2016 11:02:12   054
5. 23/01/2016 11:02:17   062
6. 23/01/2016 11:02:22   058
7. 23/01/2016 11:02:27   056

And so on until

N. 23/01/2016 12:00:01   059

After it has generated it saves generated values in a plain text file.

Comment: That doesn't look like a consistent 5 second interval, there's a difference of 55 seconds between row 2 and 3, 5 seconds between the following and somewhere around 57-58 minutes between 7 and 8. Please be consistent when asking for how to generate a pattern.

Comment: At @LasseV.Karlsen it was just a mistake it is supposed to be 5 seconds

Comment: How does the random number come into play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
var fromDate = DateTime.Now;
var toDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);


List<string> timeslice = new List<string>();
while(fromDate< toDate)
{
    timeslice.Add(fromDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));

    fromDate = fromDate.AddSeconds(5);
}
```

Working [`Code`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f1zhyU)

Comment: Thanks @ hari how do i add the date  and the last genrated number then display them in a list  view and save them in a plain text

Comment: is it winform or wpf? in winform you can do this , loop through collection and add string `listView1.Add();`

Comment: To save them into **textfile** use `File.WriteAllLines("filename",timeslice );`

Comment: Sorry @ harry my reputation is still low

Comment: @tallman That's fine, you can close it as answer by clicking the green checkmark next to that answer.

Comment: @tallman you can close it as an answer by clicking the green checkmark next to that answer.

Answer (score 0):

A method which is little more LINQ.

```
var fromDate = DateTime.Now;
var toDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);

var dateTimes = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
    .Select(x => fromDate.AddSeconds(x * 5))
    .TakeWhile(x => x <= toDate)
    .Select(x => x.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"))
    .ToList();
```